# Determinando o top-20 em determinado ano de uma tabela de scrobbles do last.fm

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Boa tarde!

Criei uma tabela em uma base de testes MariaDB (XAMPP) para armazenar todos os meus scrobbles (vezes que escutei alguma música) do site Last.FM. Usei [essa ferramenta](https://benjaminbenben.com/lastfm-to-csv/) para gerar o CSV e importei os dados à tabela. O código CREATE (gerado pelo heidisql) é o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE `scrobbles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `artist` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `album` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `title` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `datahora` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Gostaria de saber agora como listar as 20 músicas mais ouvidas (colunas `title` e `artist` duplicarem) de um certo ano.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptando [da resposta do meu repost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65190849/4836556) no SO mundial:

Se você quer para um ano único, você pode agregar, classificar e limitar:

```
select artist, album, title, count(*) cnt
from scrobbles
where datahora >= '2019-01-01' and datahora < '2020-01-01'
group by artist, album, title
order by count(*) desc limit 100
```

Adicionei o campo album para evitar que faixas homônimas de álbuns diferentes sejam agrupadas juntas.